# How to make class based view accept parameters from URL or hardcoded in URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am working on a class based generic view that takes a model name as an argument and processes that model name to get some more parameters.  I had it working fine when I hardcoded the model name into an entry in the URLconf:

```
url(r'^generic/', ResultCreateView.as_view(model = 'SomeTask'))
```

Snippets of the class based view:

```
class ResultCreateView(CreateView):
    model = None #this is here, expecting to be overwritten, because otherwise I get an error saying I can't pass in the 'model' kwarg above because 'model' is not already an attribute of the class
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.model = get_model_object_from_modelname(kwargs['model'])
        self.form_class = my_custom_function_to_generate_a_formclass(self.model)
        self.template_name = self.model.template #template_name is an attribute I set on the model class
        return super(ResultCreateView,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I tried to switch to passing the model parameter in via the url, i.e.:

```
url(r'^tasks/(?P<model>\w+)$', ResultCreateView.as_view())
```

my custom **init** method no longer works.  I get:

> ResultCreateView is missing a queryset. Define ResultCreateView.model, ResultCreateView.queryset, or override ResultCreateView.get_queryset()

I can't figure out where/when the 'model' argument gets passed in from the URL pattern to the view class.  Ideally, I would like to be able to make this view work in either case (hardcoded parameter in URLconf or parameter from URL pattern) but I don't know where to put the code that does the processing so that it happens at the right time.  Where is the right place to put that code, or is there another approach I should be using?

EDIT: (Additional complication: I need to decorate the view with a decorator that takes 'model' as an argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters will be passed to the actual request handler methods, not to the `__init__` method of the view. so, in case of a GET request:

```
class ResultCreateView(CreateView):
    model = None

    def get(self, request, model_name):
        self.model = get_model_object_from_modelname(model_name)
        self.form_class = my_custom_function_to_generate_a_formclass(self.model)
        self.template_name = self.model.template #template_name is an attribute I set on the model class
        return super(ResultCreateView,self).get(request, model_name)
```